# PHP foreach sort descending

Tags: php, sorting, foreach

Newbie here... I'm scratching my head and cannot quite figure out how to sort these discussion comments by ID in DESC order.

The other posts on this site indicate a 2 part solution - to create two parameters.  (1) to Sort and (2) to name the function which compares the two elements.
Right there... I'm lost... but trying hard to understand.

I think this is the main part of the code that needs tweaking:

```
    <?php $discList = wtis_get_discussions($post->ID);
       foreach($discList as $discInfo){
    ?>
```

Any advise?

Found it!

```
//Get log details

function wtis_get_discussions($show_id){

    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . WTIS_DISC_TBNAME;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE show_id=$show_id ORDER BY message_date";

//echo "<br/>Sql: " . $sql;

$wpdb->show_errors = true;

$discussionList = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);

return $discussionList;

}
```

Now what... really do appreciate your help guys.

Comment: now you have to look on what `wtis_get_discussions` does, as its the function that gets you the data you want to sort.

Comment: http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Where does the data come from? If it comes from a database then it should handle the sorting.

Comment: Include the definition for `wtis_get_discussions()` in your question body.

Comment: Thanks!  Looking for the function wtis_get_discussions... it's not in the function's php file... i inherited this website ;-(

Comment: added the definition for wtis_get_discussions() as requested by Jared Farrish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add an optional argument to that function for `$order_by = 'message_date'`, and then use that in the query in the function. That way you can sort by default and if necessary, do a different `ORDER BY` and direction.

```
function wtis_get_discussions($show_id, $order_by = 'message_date'){

    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . WTIS_DISC_TBNAME;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE show_id=$show_id ORDER BY $order_by";

    //echo "<br/>Sql: " . $sql;

    $wpdb->show_errors = true;

    $discussionList = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);

    return $discussionList;
}
```

Then:

```
<?php $discList = wtis_get_discussions($post->ID);
   foreach($discList as $discInfo){
?>

<?php $discList = wtis_get_discussions($post->ID, 'message_date DESC');
   foreach($discList as $discInfo){
?>

<?php $discList = wtis_get_discussions($post->ID, 'show_id DESC');
   foreach($discList as $discInfo){
?>
```

You would need to be careful to escape and clean the `$order_by` value if it's not something you've accepted from outside your app (e.g., is inherently insecure or potentially invalid content).

Comment: High Five!! That worked.  You are my hero for the day.

Answer (score 0):

if `$discList` is an array of comments with `ID` field, this may do it for you:

```
<?php
function mycmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['ID'] == $b['ID']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['ID'] < $b['ID']) ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($discList, "mycmp");
?>
```